# Ruby CSV, using square brackets as row separators

Tags: ruby, csv, fastercsv

I'm trying to use square brackets '[]' as a row separator in a CSV file. I must use this exact format for this project (output needs to match LEDES98 law invoicing format exactly).

I'm trying to do this:

```
CSV.open('output.txt', 'w', col_sep: '|', row_sep: '[]') do |csv|
     #Do Stuff
end
```

But Ruby won't take `row_sep: '[]'` and throws this error:

```
lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:2309:in `initialize': empty char-class: /[]\z/ (RegexpError)
```

I've tried escaping the characters with /'s, using double quotes, etc, but nothing has worked yet. What's the way to do this?

Comment: I don't think you can do it with the CSV class as it is. You may need to do two part processing. First, use `col_sep` and not `row_sep`. Then rewrite each line by wrapping it with `[ ... ]`.

Comment: could you add a sample of the data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `CSV#encode_re`: the parameter `row_sep: "|[]\n"` is converted to a Regexp.

What can redefine this method:

```
class CSV
  def encode_re(*chunks)
    encode_str(*chunks)
  end
end
CSV.open('output.txt', 'w', col_sep: '|', row_sep: "|[]\n"
  ) do |csv|
   csv << [1,2,3]
   csv << [4,5,6]
end
```

The result is:

```
1|2|3|[]
4|5|6|[]
```

I found no side effect, but I don't feel comfortble to redefine CSV, so I would recommend to create a new CSV-variant:

```
#Class to create LEDES98
class LEDES_CSV < CSV
  def encode_re(*chunks)
    encode_str(*chunks)
  end
end
LEDES_CSV.open('output.txt', 'w', col_sep: '|', row_sep: "|[]\n"
  ) do |csv|
   csv << [1,2,3]
   csv << [4,5,6]
end
```

Then you can use the 'original' CSV and for LEDES-files you can use the LEDES_CSV.

Answer (score 0):

Given an input string of the form

```
s = "[cat][dog][horsey\nhorse]"
```

you could use something like

```
s.scan(/\[(.*?)\]/m).flatten
```

which would return `["cat", "dog", "horsey\nhorse"]` and process that with CSV module.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried

```
require 'csv'
#Create LEDES98
CSV.open('output.txt', 'w', col_sep: '|', row_sep: '[]') do |csv|
     csv << [1,2,3]
     csv << [4,5,6]
end
```

and I got

```
1|2|3[]4|5|6[]
```

Which csv/ruby-version do you use? My `CSV::VERSION` is 2.4.7, my ruby version is *1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32]*.

Another remark:
If I look at the example files in http://www.ledes.org/ then you need additional newlines. I would recommed to use:

```
require 'csv'
#Create LEDES98
CSV.open('output.txt', 'w', col_sep: '|', row_sep: "[]\n") do |csv|
     csv << [1,2,3,nil]
     csv << [4,5,6,nil]
end
```

Result:

```
1|2|3|[]
4|5|6|[]
```

The additional nils gives you the last `|` before the [].

---

I tested on another computer with ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20) [i386-mingw32] and get the same error.

I researched a bit and can isolate the problem:

```
p "[]"      #[]
p "\[\]"    #[]     <--- Problem
p "\\[\\]"  #\\[\\]
```

You can't mask the `[`. If you mask it once, Ruby produces `[` (without the mask sign). If you mask it twice, you mask only the \, not the ].

Comment: Ruby version 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.4.0]

Comment: I tested on another computer with _ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20) [i386-mingw32]_ - Now I have the same error.

Comment: I found a solution with a newer ruby-version. see my [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14269091/676874)